# SQL INSERT with ExecuteNonQuery() inserts extra decimal places

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an asp.net application written in C#. I have an insert button that takes user-entered information on the page, adds the values to a list, and sends the list to a method that inserts the data to a MSSQL database table. 
Everything is working as expected except for fields with data type set to 'float' on the backend. 
If I enter a value such as '70.3' in the textbox for field 'Temperature', the value inserted actually becomes '70.3000030517578'. I also have a button that calls an update method. If I change the '70.3000030517578' back to '70.3' and send it to the update method, then 70.3 is correctly inserted in the database. 
Here is my SqlCommand Parameter code:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@temp", listIn[0].Temperature == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : listIn[0].Temperature);
```

After the above line runs, I check the parameter in debugging mode and confirmed that the Value is 70.3. See screenshot: [image: temp_insert]

I compared this to the update since that method works properly and the properties become:[image: temp_update]

The two differences are in the DbType and SqlDbType. 
So I tried the below line which did not change anything (still adds extra decimal places):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@temp", SqlDbType.Float).Value = listIn[0].Temperature == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : listIn[0].Temperature;
```

If I change the data type on the backend to decimal(18,3) then the insert method correctly inserts '70.300'. Is my only option to use decimal data type instead of float? We would prefer to use float, if possible. Any ideas are welcomed. I have not been doing this long so I apologize if my question is not detailed enough.

Comment: How many decimals you need for your value? Define your float field with that precision and look here [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) (I would use a decimal type)

Comment: The data is variable. It could be anywhere from 0 to maybe 3 decimal places (but maybe more). Thanks, I will take a look.

Comment: `70.3.ToString("G20") == "70.299999999999997"`. There is no such thing as 70.3 as a float.

Comment: @triSaratops: What was the solution here?

Comment: @AnkitKumar I ditched float and used decimal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about [Using decimal, float, and real Data](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912(v=sql.105).aspx)

> Approximate numeric data types do not store the exact values specified
>   for many numbers; they store an **extremely close approximation** of the
>   value. For many applications, the tiny difference between the
>   specified value and the stored approximation is not noticeable. At
>   times, though, the difference becomes noticeable. Because of the
>   approximate nature of the float and real data types, do not use these
>   data types when exact numeric behavior is required, such as in
>   financial applications, in operations involving rounding, or in
>   equality checks. Instead, use the integer, decimal, money, or
>   smallmoney data types.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably running into something related to floating point precision/error. 70.3 is not a value that can be precisely represented in the float/real type. The closest value that can be stored (following IEEE-754 standards) is 70.30000305175781

http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

If you need accuracy in base 10, decimal is probably the way to go. Otherwise, you'll have to do the rounding yourself.